# Creating tables in a database with same name

Tags: mysql, database

I'm working on a web app in which there is a common database and users can create tables in that database, and then retrieve data from it. A user can have access to a table from the database only if he created it. So my question is if two different users created a group with the same name, won't that be a problem since my data is being fetched by referencing the table name?
How do I solve this?

edit: This is the query that i want to run everytime someone calls a function

```
CREATE TABLE `<name of table>` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`start` datetime NOT NULL,
`end` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`allDay` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'false',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

Comment: If every user is forced to use their own schema then you will not have such collisions.

Comment: Yes but the table schema is fixed since everyone's table must have the same structure and attributes. The entries, however, will be different. I'm sorry if this is something very obvious but I'm a noob at web dev. I updated the question with the sql query that everyone will run when they create a table, but they can give different names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about prefixing the table names with the user's ID?

```
e.g. user_1_their-table-name
```

You'll run into problems if the first character is a digit so I've added user_ at the very start.

Comment: This seems like a great solution. thank you